# Angular 4, можно ли настроить сборку на сервере?

Tags: angular4

добрый день, разбираюсь с фреймворком Angular 4, пишу небольшие компоненты. очень расстраивает длительность процесса сборки. Есть ли возможность использовать некоторые облачные ресурсы для сборки ангуляровского проекта, так чтобы с локального ноутбука можно было писать код, а собирались все эти мегатонны модулей удаленно? какие есть варианты по данному вопросу